# Lazy loading being ignored by activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I found my inherited resources controller is ignoring extra parameters when querying through REST. I did a test replacing the inherited resources method and found out that the model itself is ignoring extra where's.

```
a = Client.where(:user_id => 1)
a.where(:project_id => 2)

a.first.project_id == '1'
```

The second where is being ignored, I see in the log that this is being select:

```
SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: why dont you use `a = Client.where(:user_id => 1).where(:project_id => 2)` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second a.where is not changing the variable a, so you need to set a again for the second where clause:

```
a = Client.where(:user_id => 1)
a = a.where(:project_id => 2)
```